# Checking for nulls on collections

Tags: c#

If I've got an array or generic list or even a dictionary and I want to first do some checks to see if the object is valid, do I:

1. Check for null
2. Just check for someCollection.count > 0
3. both

Do I check for null then check for count or is checking for count good enough and I don't need to check for null first?

My problem with OOP and C# often is to know when to check for nulls vs just count on collections.  And if it's null then what to return if it's null and lest say you're tryign to return an itemin that collection through a property as an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can't check for Count on a null collection.

An empty collection and a null collection are two different things. So you should check for both, otherwise always initialize your collections so you'll never run into null problems. Or for a simple solution, just return a new collection, then let your calling code handle the count check.

```
List<Type> someCollection = new List<Type();

if(someCollection == null)
    return new List<Type>();
```

Comment: well what if this calling code is in your mark-up?  I don't want a bunch of logic in my mark-up for doing count checks, etc. but the method that is referencing this property needs an object back regardless if it's null or not.  How to handle this is my pain point.

Comment: Are you saying your property needs a backing field? Then just what I  suggested and have the backing field initialized to a new instance of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Count will not work on null objects.

Here is some boiler plate code you can use:

```
Debug.Assert(collection != null);
Debug.Assert(collection.Count > 0);
if (collection == null) {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
}
if (collection.Count == 0) {
    throw new ArgumentException("collection should have at least one member"); 
}
```

Asserting is really important and should be practiced by more .Net devs.

Crashing early can be key to writing robust code. If there are any parameters that a method you are writing should NEVER get passed, it may be better to crash at that point as opposed to writing corrupt data to the DB.

You also need a robust logging mechanism in place so you can log all those nasty things that are going on.

Comment: Asserts are for checking conditions that must be true, so aren't really useful when validating arguments to public methods like this.

Comment: Are you saying that public methods do not have pre conditions that must be true? Keep in mind when compiling in release all those asserts vanish. Its a tool to help you stay honest while writing your code. It forces the debugger to nag you.

Comment: The method's preconditions are enforced by throwing exceptions here so the asserts are redundant. I agree in general that asserts are underused however.

Comment: Sure, having said that, Debug.Assert nags you **ALWAYS** in debug mode, throwing an exception may or may not nag you depending on weather you are breaking on exceptions or not.

Comment: True, in that case it would be useful.

Comment: but you may not want to crash.  In this case, I don't.  If it's null and the property is to return an object from that list back, then what do you do??

Comment: you don't always want your code to throw an exception and halt your entire application

Comment: everything depends on the problem at hand, do you care to share some code with us?

Answer (score 0):

When you have control over the creation of these collections, you can make your API easier to use by *never* returning null.  If there are no elements, just return an empty collection.  If performance is a concern, you can create a single static instance and always return that, or use an [EmptyEnumerator](http://www.csharp411.com/c-empty-enumerator/).

Comment: yes, performance is a concern.  We're ane-commerce site getting 500,000 unique hits a month